# Is it possible to apply a CSS stylesheet to the file index view of a local directory in a browser?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML file that i would like to display the files listed in a directory that sits on a local machine. For example, I have an html element which displays the file directory in the default browser.

`<li><a href="file:///C:/">Home</a></li>`

Is there a way to apply a CSS StyleSheet to that page? I've seen a few options that are specific to apache but not for local directories.

Thanks

Comment: i read 10 times. but cant catch your point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this depends on the browser.

Comment: @KarSho: He wants to apply a stylesheet to `file:///C:/` when it's displayed in a browser. (Open that URL in your browser if you're using Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

The rendering of file:/// locations are controlled by the individual browsers.  For example, in the chromium codebase the header can be found at

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/base/dir_header.html

The simple answer is that there is no cross-browser solution.